# How to programmatically set a text-selection in TBCEditor?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I use this version of TBCEditor in Delphi 10.4.1:

https://github.com/maciej-izak/TBCEditor-1

When I try to programmatically set a text-selection:

```
Editor.SelectionBeginPosition.Line := i;
```

...then the compiler shows this error message:

> [dcc32 Error] Form1.pas(422): E2064 Left side cannot be assigned to

So how can I programmatically set a text-selection in TBCEditor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used that control but I had a look at the [source code](https://github.com/maciej-izak/TBCEditor-1/blob/master/Source/BCEditor.Editor.Base.pas) and found at line 652 a method that seems to do what you are looking for: `SetCaretAndSelection`.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I had searched in the source code for HOURS, but I must have been blind! You helped me a lot! How can I show my gratitude?